# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Nickname or Acronymn

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Does Windows Server 2008 R2 have an official, or unofficial nickname / acronymn?

W2K8? Shorthorn?

Comment: Let's coin one.  How about 2K8R2 ? Sounds like a droid :)

Comment: HAHA @ Shorthorn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Centro** (mid-market range) and **Cougar** (small business) were codenames used for the current server family while it was under development.

[image]

Comment: Molly this is an impressive graphic. So far I like Centro. Cougar has other connotations.

Comment: I'm convinced : deleting my answer.

Comment: I could never call it "cougar" without snickering.